Possible errors in my textbook about Cavendish experiment?
We all know the Cavendish experiment and but my textbook "Concepts of Physics" by HC Verma on page 204 has given something extra which I dont get.
Let me write what it said

Let mass of heavy ball be $M$, mass of small ball be $m$
distance between centres of heavy ball and small ball placed close to it be $r$
the deflection of the dumb bell as it comes to equilibrium be $\theta$
torsional constant of string be $k$
length of rod be $l$ and distance between scale and the mirror be $D.$
When it comes to rotational equilibrium net torque must be $\theta$, so $2F(l/2) = k\theta$
$GMml/r^2=kθ$
$G=k\theta r^2/Mml$

I have no problem till now but my problem will start now

Now the heavy balls are shifted in such a way that they are placed on the same horizontal circle at the same distance from the smaller balls but on the opposite side.

(my question: is the 'distance' being talked about is the one from the small ball to the big ball at equilibrium?)

As the heavy balls are shifted to new positions, the dumb bell rotates. If it was settled previously at $\theta$ deviated from the mean position, it will now settle at the same angle $\theta$ on the other side. Thus the total deflection of the dumb bell due to change in position of heavy balls is $2\theta$.

(my question: Let me take the distance that I asked in the previous question from small ball to the big ball at equilibrium. If my assumption is true then how can we say that if we shift the heavy balls then the angle deviated will again be $\theta$?
I have 2 arguments for that:-

The torsional torque and the gravitational force torque will then start to add up for some time(and not subtract from the starting only as they did when we started the experiment intially), since say if the torsional torque was anti clockwise before shifting the bigger blocks, and the bigger blocks posed a clockwise torque, then after shifting the heavy balls, the gravitational torque will be anticlockwise, and the torsional torque will also be anticlockwise for some time since the string was still twisted at equilbrium position, when the heavy balls were being shifted. Since this condition is not same as the initial condition when the experiment started, (because the torsional torque and gravitational torque  were subtracted from starting only when the experiment intially started but now they will add), so the angle deviated will also not be the same as before, so it will not be $\theta$.

If the the distance that I asked in the previous question from small ball to the big ball at equilibrium is actually the distance at which heavy ball are being shifted then if intially when the experiment was started, the big ball and heavy ball were at a distance $r$ apart, at equilibrium they will be at a distance say 'x' apart (also $\theta$ is rotated to get that equilbrium), and if the heavy balls are shifted to opposite sides at $x$ distance, and the experiment is started again then as the distance between the small ball and big ball is $x$ now(not $r$ as it was initially) then my intuition says that the angle rotated will be less than $\theta$)



Thus the total deflection of the dumb bell due to change in position of heavy balls is $2\theta$. The reflected light beam then deviates by $4\theta$. If the linear displacement of light spot is $d$ then $4θ=d/D$ ($D$ was the distance between the scale and the mirror), $\theta = d/4D$,

Hence $G = kdr^2/4MmlD$
Now my final question. I believe we could calculate $\theta$ when the rod comes at equilibrium position from when the experiment was started only. Why was there a need for us to shift the heavy balls and then deviate the dumb bell by $2\theta$ to calculate all this?

the book is correct. To maximise precision, the design of the experiment has to be very well-thought-out. Nothing should be moving when the data is taken, and you also want to adjust the balls until the distances are equal in the two cases, just opposite, and then just measure the angle of deflection. It is some tiny deflection, so you can set it up and exit the vicinity, so that even air disturbance can be minimised.

@naturallyInconsistent Could you answer the 3 questions I proposed in an elaborative manner through the form of an answer? It would be very helpful to me and I shall be much obliged.

Is the 'distance' being talked about is the one from the small ball to the big ball at equilibrium?
Yes
$\dots$ how can we say that if we shift the heavy balls then the angle deviated will again be θ?
Symmetry as shown in the diagram below.
.
Textbook - "Now the heavy balls are shifted in such a way that they are placed on the same horizontal circle at same distance from the smaller balls but on the opposite side."
The mechanism, KFl, for adjusting the torsion wire and hence the orientation of the torsion does not influence the mechanism,mMP, for moving the large masses.

Why was there a need for us to shift the heavy balls and then deviate the dumb bell by 2θ to calculate all this?
The angle of deflection was very small and so moving the large masses from one side of the smaller masses to the other side gave twice the deflection and hence improved the accuracy of the experiment.
Notes
The description in the book is an edited version of Cavendish's experiment and simplifies the observations that Cavendish made to make it easier for a student to understand.
For example, the smaller balls suspended from the torsion wire were always oscillating when he took readings to obtain the mean position of oscillation. This was because it would take many hours for the balls to stop oscillating because of very light damping.
Cavendish did not use an optical lever arrangement to measure the deflection, rather he used a vernier scale illuminated by a lamp and observed through a telescope.
He found the torsional constant of the wire by measuring the period of oscillation of the horizontal beam to which the smaller balls were attached and the geometry of the arrangement.
Perhaps most surprisingly Cavendish did not measure the gravitational constant $G$, rather he measured the average density of the Earth using an unusual method of analysis.
Cavendish's 1798 paper to the Royal Society with the diagrams right at the end.
There are many review articles available on the Internet which are designed to help with the understanding of Cavendish's experiment with The Cavendish Experiment as a Tool for Historical Understanding of Science written by Steffen Ducheyne as one of the most detailed.

Thank you for this answer. But what about the twisting of the rope when the heavy balls were being shifted? Wasn't the string already twisted then? Wouldn't it cause a torsional torque in the direction of the gravitational torque after the shifting happens(for some time)?

What I mean can be understood by the 2 arguments about which I wrote in my answer(maybe I misunderstood something).
